# Python code to do a insert in scylladb using python having custom frozen field

Tags: python, scylla

My db was created with below configuration

CREATE KEYSPACE chat WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
use chat;

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS conversation (
id TEXT,
message TEXT,
audio TEXT,
metadata MAP<TEXT, TEXT>,
timestamp TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
user_id TEXT,
interaction_id TEXT,
created_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
prompt frozen,
response frozen,
interaction_details MAP<TEXT, TEXT>,
regeneration_details LIST<frozen>,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, interaction_id, created_timestamp)
);

I have written below code to a simple insert in scylladb using python

```
import uuid
import traceback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from config import db_config as db

def connect_to_cassandra(local_port, cassandra_username, cassandra_password, keyspace):
    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=cassandra_username, password=cassandra_password)
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=local_port, auth_provider=auth_provider)
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace=keyspace)
    session.default_consistency_level = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM
    return session, cluster


local_port = db.LOCAL_PORT
remote_cassandra_host = db.REMOTE_CASSANDRA_HOST
remote_cassandra_port = int(db.REMOTE_CASSANDRA_PORT)
cassandra_username = db.CASSANDRA_USERNAME
cassandra_password = db.CASSANDRA_PASSWORD
cassandra_keyspace = db.CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE


user_id = '735f0735-8851-45b4-b0a3-dae7061b024a'
interaction_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
created_timestamp = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
interaction_details = {"title": "Hi"}

prompt_data = {
    "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
    "message": "Hello",
    "audio": None,
    "metadata": {'type': 'text'},
    "timestamp": created_timestamp
    }

response_data = {
    "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
    "message": "Hi",
    "audio": None,
    "metadata": {"type": "text"},
    "timestamp": created_timestamp
    }
response_data = None
regeneration_details_data = None

insert_query = "INSERT INTO chat (user_id, interaction_id, created_timestamp, interaction_details, prompt, regeneration_details, response) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

try:
    cassandra_session = connect_to_cassandra(local_port, cassandra_username, cassandra_password, cassandra_keyspace)
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

insert_ps=cassandra_session.prepare(query=insert_query)
cassandra_session.execute(query=insert_ps, parameters=[user_id, interaction_id, created_timestamp, interaction_details, prompt_data,regeneration_details_data,response_data])
```

I am getting error

cassandra_session.execute(
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2677, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2720, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2979, in cassandra.cluster.Session._create_response_future
File "cassandra/query.py", line 905, in cassandra.query.bind_params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

If i set response_data to None. Then query get executed fine. But if I try to pass response_data, then I am getting error.
What am I doing wrong?

Mentioned in above details

Comment: I think you have a typo in the `CREATE TABLE` command, is it `response frozen<conversation>`?

Answer (score 0):

The Python driver documentation in https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/user_defined_types/ explains how to pass user-defined types as bind variables. The documentation suggests a few options, such as creating a special class, or "registering" the user-defined type, but you can also do it without a class or registrations, using a named tuple. I don't think it just works naively with a dict, e.g.,

```py
import collections
# user_type("a", 1, "b", 2) creates a named tuple with component names "a", "b"
# and values 1, 2. The return of this function can be used to bind to a UDT.
# The number of arguments is assumed to be even.
def user_type(*args):
    return collections.namedtuple('user_type', args[::2])(*args[1::2])
...
execute(stmt, [user_type('a', 0, 'b', 2)])
```